# Нужны готовые нейронные сети, которые распознают объекты на картинке или видеопоследовательности, а также их описание

Tags: нейронные-сети

Обращаюсь с просьбой накидать ссылок на источники, в которых имеются готовые обученные нейронные сети. Неважно как они распространяются, в открытом доступе или платно, главное, это название нейронной сети и описание о ней, что делает, как обучена и т.д. Желательно в подробностях. И пару фотографий с примерами работ. Да, я гуглил, но большинство источников показывают, как написать свою сеть, а мне нужны готовые сети. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предобученные модели на то и предобучены, что их обучили распознавать не "объекты" вообще, а конкретный, обычно весьма узкий класс объектов. Какие именно объекты вы собрались распознавать? Ну вот вам описание готовой сети

https://towardsdatascience.com/real-time-object-detection-with-yolo-9dc039a2596b

вот

https://neurohive.io/ru/novosti/adapis-nejroset-dlya-adaptivnoj-instance-segmentacii-izobrazheniya/

или вот

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/07/computer-vision-implementing-mask-r-cnn-image-segmentation/

пара из сотен в сети.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки. Мне на диплом описания готовых нейросетей нужны, а не сами нейросети. Не важно, что они распознают, главное их название и описание их работы.